# Probability that the millionth decay occurs within 100.2 seconds?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Radioactive decay of an element occurs according to a Poisson process
>   with rate $10,000$ per second. What is the approximate probability
>   that the millionth decay occurs within $100.2$ seconds?

Let $X$ be the number of decays and the number of expected decays within $100.2$ seconds is $\lambda=100.2\cdot10000=1002000.$ Thus $\bar{X}\sim \text{Poi}(1002000)$ and $\mu=1002000, \ \sigma=\sqrt{1002000}=1000.995.$

How to I formulate "probability that the millionth decay occurs within $100.2$ seconds?"

Is it $P(X>1000000)?$ I don't se how.

Comment: It's rather $P(X\geq 1000000)$, otherwise you're fine.

Comment: But why? I don't intuitively understand why it's $P(X\ge 1000000)?$

Comment: Because $X$ counts the number of decays. If $X\geq 4$, then it means that the first, second, third **and fourth** decays occured in the timespan of $100.2$s.

Comment: So $X$ counts the number of decays within $100.2$ seconds? Why isn't it then just $X=4$? Because all the previous ones must have happened if the fourth have happened.

Comment: I still don't see how $X\ge 4 $ tells me that the decays 1 throught 4 happened withing $100.2$ seconds.

Comment: I tried to make an answer, hope it's clear.

Comment: @Parseval: Suppose $X = 6$; that is, $6$ decays occurred in the interval from $0$ to $100.2$ seconds.  In particular, the first four decays must have occurred in the first $100.2$ seconds.  There is nothing special about the number $6$ in this regard, *except that* it is greater than or equal to $4$.  If you were to replace the $6$ with any number that is $4$ or greater, the reasoning would continue to apply.  That is why any $X \geq 4$ tells you decays $1$ through $4$ occurred within $100.2$ seconds.

Comment: @BrianTung - But I interpert $P(X \ge a)$ as "the probability that the number of decays within $100.2$ seconds is greater than or equal to  $a$." But I only wanted $X=1000000,$ so why can't it just be $X=1000000$ instead? I'm sorry, I don't really know how to formulate the question properly.

Comment: @Parseval: You do want "greater than or equal to $a$."  If you set $X = 1000000$ (rather than greater than or equal to), you miss all those cases where the first million happened, and then also a few more happened too.  The first million still happened in time, it's just that some more also did.

Comment: In other words, $P(X = 1000000)$ is *not* the probability that the first million happened in time.  It's the probability that the first million happened in time, *and* the next one *didn't*.  Unless that's the probability you want, you shouldn't require equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is equal to the number of decays over a given timespan of $100.2$ seconds. It could be any non-negative integer (theoretically).

If $X=3$ then $3$ decays occurred during than timespan. The fourth will then occur later. The same goes if $X<3$.

If $X\geq 4$, it means that there were a number of decays at least equal to $4$, hence the fourth was one of them.

It follows that $$P(X\geq 1000000)$$
is the correct formulation.

Comment: Ok now the understanding clicked into place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a Poisson process with expected value $1,002,000$.  The chance that the millionth decay has not happened yet is the sum of the probabilities of exactly $0,1,2,\ldots ,999,999$ decays having happened.  I believe you are supposed to use the normal approximation.  Based on the figures you quote, a million decays is just about $2\sigma $ low so you need the chance that a random normal is greater than mean-$2\sigma $.

Comment: You write that "The chance that the millionth decay has not happened yet is the sum of the probabilities of 0,1,2,…,999,999 decays having happened". Why?

Comment: I added the word "exactly".  If there are $0$ decays in the period the millionth decay happens afterward.  Similarly if there are only $999,999$.

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of decays in $100.2$ seconds is $1002000$. Thus,
the Poisson distribution for exactly $k$ decays in $100.2$ seconds is
$$
\frac{1002000^k}{k!}e^{-1002000}
$$
The mean of this distribution is $1002000$, and the variance is $1002000$.

The probability of at least $1000000$ decays in $100.2$ seconds is
$$
\sum_{k=1000000}^\infty\frac{1002000^k}{k!}e^{-1002000}=0.9771959041
$$

---

The probability that a normally distributed random variable is greater than $\frac{2000.5}{\sqrt{1002000}}=1.998502496$ standard deviations less than the mean is approximately $0.9771688952$, which matches the exact value pretty closely.
$$
%\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\frac{2000.5}{\sqrt{1002000}}}^{\infty}e^{-t^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}t=0.9771688952
$$